# Azure Functions V1 user secrets

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions and I need to develop a few V1 (.Net Framework) functions that will have connections strings and other secrets that I cannot add to source control, I have to use V1 because I will need to use some libraries only available on classic .net

I have seen several articles on how to use secrets with V2 and V3 (.net core) and I have seen some advising to install `Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets` following the directions on the [project site](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders#usersecretsconfigbuilder) and [this tutorial](https://jeffreyfritz.com/2017/11/modern-configuration-for-asp-net-4-7-1-with-configurationbuilders/) mentioned on that site

So basically what I'm supposed to do is having an `app.config` file then create `sections` that will map to the proper Builder on app startup, however, azure functions don't seem to work with config files, I have created and tested and whenever I call `System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` it loads what is on the `local.settings.json` file. I don't see anywhere this can be changed.

So summing up, what I'm trying to do is have a file with some config in dev and then use Azure Key Vault once deployed.

How can I do this?
Is there a way to use a config file with Azure functions?

Answer (score 2):

I vote for ["put the secrets in key vault"](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Integrate-Key-Vault-Secrets-With-Azure-Functions/). This should work for any version.

Comment: So, on dev I would have to add dummy values to the Env Variables, right?

Comment: Does this work locally? Seems to be an incomplete answer to me